# ldapsearch for users by partial memberOf value

Tags: search, ldap, ldap-query

I have a list of groups and I need to extract users by knowing partially memberOf value

Example:

```
# for group AAA
ldapsearch -w V1ZEYK -D "cn=XXXXXX,ou=Service Users,ou=User Accounts,dc=uuu,dc=yyy,dc=xxx,dc=net" -H ldaps://<link>:<port> -b "dc=uuu,dc=yyy,dc=xxx,dc=net" -s sub memberOf="CN=AAA,OU=Groups,DC=uuu,DC=yyy,DC=xxx,DC=net" | grep "cn:"
# returns "cn: 12345"

# for group BBB
... -s sub memberOf="CN=BBB,DC=uuu,DC=yyy,DC=xxx,DC=net" | grep "cn:"
# returns nothing, meaning memberOf DC part is different that I dont know of
```

1. How should I pass partial filter so the search could return user cns?
2. Is there a way (and should I) pass wildcard filters for flags `-D` and `-b`?

Tried:

```
... -s sub memberOf="CN=BBB*"...
... -s sub memberOf="*CN=BBB*"...
# returns nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

The LDAP specification do not allow substring searches of Distinguished Names.
(like "CN=BBB,DC=uuu,DC=yyy,DC=xxx,DC=net")

I think you will need to write some code.